# How to click on the sub-menu using selenium webdriver?

Tags: selenium-webdriver

I have to click on the "Candidate" submenu, the HTML for the same is given below

[image]

Comment: Please modify your question and include the code you are trying to use that is causing you a problem.

Comment: Please read how to create a [minimal complete verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and add the missing information to your Post :) If you haven't read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) yet i recommend to do so :) Welcome to StackOverflow

Answer (score 0):

an example in c# is below:

```
driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//a[contains(@title, 'Candidate')]")).Click();
```

or alternatively:

```
driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//a[contains(@href, '/candidate/search')]")).Click();
```

Answer (score 0):

dear friend you can take hint of below answer..where link is www.amazon.in

```
   for(int i=1;i<=webTableRows.size();i+=2) {
        ArrayList <WebElement> webTableCols = (ArrayList<WebElement>)driver.findElements(By.xpath(".//*[@id='navFooter']/div[4]/table/tbody/tr["+i+"]/td"));
        System.out.println(webTableCols.size());
        for (int j=1;j<=webTableCols.size();j+=2) {
                if(i==3 && j==11) {
                    break;
                }
                WebElement strElement = driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='navFooter']/div[4]/table/tbody/tr["+i+"]/td["+j+"]/a"));


                if(strElement.isDisplayed()) {

                    String strData = strElement.getText();
                    String[] newString = strData.split("\n");

                    System.out.print(newString[0]);
        }
```